# Remotely Grant server\localuser access to a folder by using PowerShell

Tags: permissions, powershell-2.0, acl

I have 100 servers where a local folder d:\backupmedia\ exists and every server has a local user as \backupuser , now I have to grant FullControl permission to this folder for this localuser using powershell. I tried following code which works fine for domain user but not for local user as I get following error,

> Exception calling "SetAccessRule" with "1" argument(s): "Some or all identity references could not >be translated."

Code I tried,

```
foreach ($srvr in Get-Content .\Dev_Servers.txt) 
{
$AccountName="backupuser"
$Right="FullControl"
$Inheritperm="ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit"
$Principal="$srvr\$AccountName"
$Permission =$Principal,$Right,$Inheritperm,"None","Allow"
$AccessRule=New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($Permission)
$UNCPath="\\$srvr\d$\backupmedia"
$ACL = Get-Acl $UNCPath
$ACL.SetAccessRule($AccessRule)
Set-Acl $UNCPath -AclObject $ACL
}
```

I found [solution](http://www.happysysadm.com/2012/09/how-to-remotely-modify-windows-acl.html) to similar issue using fileacl utility but it seems it has been abondoned and no more available anywhere.

Please help me to fix the issue.

Comment: yes backupuser exists on remote server, code will work only if I execute script locally but if I have to execute script from a remote computer then it results in error

Comment: Yes, I've deleted my comment because I was in error! The problem is that source computer know nothin about local user on remote computer. If you add via explorer the local user on the remote folder and from source computer try get-acl $uncpath it returns a sid and not a user name. Set-acl using  remote user sid doen0t works!

Comment: @C.B. you are correct, but is there any solution to this? I need to do it on 100+ servers and currently stuck here

Comment: Maybe using powershell remote session but I can test it.